# In the Netflix Daredevil series, is the "Black Sky" concept from any comic?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil, daredevil-2015

In the [Season 1: Episode 7](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4125416/?ref_=ttep_ep7) titled *Stick*, we hear about Nobu's plan to import a *Black Sky* into Hell's Kitchen. It's insinuated to be some type of weapon.

> We find out that the Black Sky is a child, referred to as a "thing" by Stick. Stick says he killed the child/Black Sky, an event that happened off-screen. Nobu later confirms this event, and then mentions that it will be difficult to find another Black Sky. Presumably, it will also be a child/person of some sort, which is the concept I'm wondering about.

### Is this concept taken from any comic story line, either with the same or different name?

Or...

### Is this a creation unique to the new Daredevil series?

---

**Update**

With the release of Season 2, we see a little bit more information about Black Sky, that may help identify if elements of it were taken from any comic book line.

> The Black Sky is The Hand's ultimate warrior, and a notable character in the show.

Do these new details now help to relate it to a comic story?

Comment: In the F. Paul Wilson novel Black Wind, the titular Black Wind (kuroikaze) was a weapon developed by the Japanese during World War 2. It was created using a genetically modified child who is then given some kind of "potion". The child dies, and a wind of instant death is released. Seeing this episode, that's what popped into my head. I doubt Marvel is pulling from some old novel...just thought it was interesting. Black Wind is fiction, but quite well researched. Maybe Marvel pulled something similar from Japanese mythology?

Comment: The crate they shipped the Black Sky in says (in Japanese) _"Aseno Robotics"_.  That could just be a cover, though.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**No, the character/term appears to be something invented for the show.** That said, though, there are several possibilities and we can speculate based on what we know from the comics.

In the comics, Stick is a member of The Chaste - a brotherhood of warriors based out of Japan. The primary purpose of The Chaste is to oppose [The Hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hand_(comics)) - a clan of evil ninjas who worship an ancient demon. It's important to note that the final rite of becoming a member of The Hand involves drinking a potion composed of, among other things, demon blood, which transforms the subject into a state of undeath. This is, arguably, The Hand's greatest weapon, as it renders their ninjas immune to pain, fear, and often even a permanent death.

We know that The Hand will be a major player in the upcoming Iron Fist series, and that they are now officially in the MCU since

> Nobu revealed himself as a warrior of The Hand, complete with their famous red uniform.

In the comics, The Hand always make it a priority to obtain artifacts or people with close ties to demonology and/or occult magic. That, along with Stick's insistence on calling the Black Sky a "thing", leads me to speculate that the weapon is actually

> a human/demon hybrid. This would explain not only WHY The Hand wanted the child, but also HOW he could be a "great weapon", as well as why the child was chained the way he was inside the container. It would also explain how there could be others out there, yet be rare and/or difficult to find.

This is also supported by the fact that Japanese & Chinese mythology are supposed to play a large part in the upcoming Iron Fist series, and there were numerous other references to Iron Fist throughout the series:

> The truck involved in Matt Murdock's accident had "Rand Corp" on the door, which is the company owned by Danny Rand's parents. The red dragon mark on Madame Gao's drugs is the Mark of [The Steel Serpent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Serpent), who is Iron Fist's primary villain.

There are also some questions regarding Madame Gao, one of the Kingpin's associates:

> When fighting Daredevil, she showed superhuman strength, throwing him across the room with only a single punch. Later, she said she was returning to "her homeland", then stated that it was "much further away" than China. She may be, in fact, a demon herself, or some other mystical villain from the comics.

All of this ties together with one word: **mysticism**.

---

**UPDATE:** As of Season 2 of Daredevil, we now know WHY the group is looking for the Black Sky:

> They want the Black Sky to lead them, and Elektra is one. It seems that her nature as a Black Sky is responsible for her inner turmoil and darkness, but we still do not know WHAT makes someone a Black Sky.

Comment: Accepting it, although it's only been 4 days and has over 28K views. I'm not sure why there are so few votes with such a high view count (astronomical to me), but there were also no downvotes. So this is the answer, as the community has clearly had the opportunity to respond.

Comment: @CreationEdge: probably loads of views from people who are just searching for Daredevil info due to the TV series and its publicity, and aren’t members here.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I didn't see it when I edited this last night. Props.

Answer (score 9):

Black Sky is not a concept/character lifted directly from the comics or any other existing Marvel media.

There are two current prevailing theories linking it/him to the comics.

- Black Sky is an Inhuman. It is mentioned that that particular Black Sky can be replaced, just that it is not easy, as there are few others and they are difficult to find. Given Marvel's recent Inhuman push, this would make a bit of sense.
- Black Sky is an incarnation or vessel of The Beast, which is a demon which leads [The Hand](http://marvel.com/universe/Hand), which Nobu was clearly a part of.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://www.quora.com/Marvels-Daredevil-TV-series/What-is-The-Black-Sky), we aren't meant to know what exactly Black Sky is yet, but should expect it to be linked to the upcoming Iron Fist series.

Comment: I'm not wanting to know exactly what Black Sky is, really. I'm just wondering if this is a story line pulled from a comic (much of the MCU stuff is related to comic arcs) or not. It could be a DD comic, or not. I'm not versed well in DD/The Hand/The Chaste/Iron Fist history to know if there's a connection, or even just a nod to some source material.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I was trying to get at--nobody knowing what a "Black Sky," is and it being pulled from a comic storyline are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Not mutually exclusive, no. For instance, a different name or multiple possibilities would be reasons people don't *know*. But, I understand your point.

Comment: The source on the page you linked saying we're not supposed to know, is just some random fan.

Comment: To be clear: I'm not saying that he or you are wrong, just that he's not exactly a reliable source for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Without bringing MCU into it Google "Japanese black sky".  I found a reference to the "very rare" first prints of Japanese wood block prints set"100 Views of Edo".  One of the set noted titled, "Fireworks Over Ryogoku Bridge" shows a black sky with fireworks surrounded by a glow. Very few are known to exist. Later prints have indigo or blue skies. Incidentally, a complete set of the 100 Views of Edo with BLACK SKIES was discovered in 1970 in the USA. Guess where? New York! In Brooklyn next to Hells Kitchen. The donor, Anna Ferris was the daughter of a prominent minister who did missionary work and helped educate poor and orphaned Japanese boys in Brooklyn. Given Daredevil's emphasis on art, I wonder if there is any possible connection.

Comment: Can you please link to the references you found?

Comment: The tie would make more sense had Fisk been interested in Black Sky, but Nobu was not shown to have any interest in art.